# Import InfoPath form into Access?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-infopath

I have a InfoPath form that I designed, and an access table with similar fields.  Is there a way to import the form into the table without writing any code?

**Note:** Access 2007 and Infopath 2007

Comment: Have you tried to import the data through the usual Get External Data choice on the main menu?

Comment: Sure did, didn't really give me what I was looking for.  Ended up writing the code.